# get a value of x and y increment with a given angle

Tags: javascript, python, trigonometry

[image: sample diagram]

**Note: Your solution can be in browser js or python. angleX will be in radians**

I want a method that takes three parameters :-

- aCord  -  (an object/dictionary with the co-ordinates of point A)
- bCord  -  (an object/dictionary with the co-ordinates of point B)
- angleX  -  (angle of rotation)

Lets say that I have a point A and a point B (any where on the screen. Not necessarily parallel as shown in the figure)

Point B is rotated angleX degrees (with point B as the center of the circle) to form point C

But instead, i want to increment b.x and b.y so it is same as c.x and c.y

Your function should return an object/dictionary with two values. An 'x-increment' and a 'y-increment' (which is how much I should increment the x and y of point B)

here is my existing code (in js)

```js
function getIncrement(aCord, bCord, angleX) {

  let r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aCord.x - bCord.x, 2) + Math.pow(aCord.x - bCord.x, 2));

  let angleY = Math.atan(Math.abs(aCord.y - bCord.y) / Math.abs(aCord.x - bCord.x));

  let cCord = {
    x: Math.cos(angleY + angleX) * r,
    y: Math.sin(angleY + angleX) * r
  };

  return {
    xIncrement: cCord.x - aCord.x,
    yIncrement: cCord.y - aCord.y
  };
}
```

*Sorry if my explaination is not good enough. I could explain in the comments if you do not understand something*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of the function to use in a JavaScript snippet. Move the mouse in the box to move the B-point (A is fixed), and the line A-C will be added dynamically. Change the angle in the input box:

```js
// The function to calculate C:
function getC(a, b, angle) {
    let sign = -1; // change to 1 if Y axis goes upward
    let radius = Math.sqrt((a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2);
    angle += Math.atan2(sign*(b.y-a.y), b.x-a.x);
    return {
        x: a.x + Math.cos(angle)*radius,
        y: a.y + sign*Math.sin(angle)*radius
    };
}

// I/O handling
function drawLine(ctx, a, b, color="black") {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    ctx.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function text(ctx, a, txt, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillText(txt, a.x+2, a.y-2);
}

function refresh(ctx, a, b, c) {
    outputB.textContent = Math.round(b.x) + "," + Math.round(b.y);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    drawLine(ctx, a, b, "black");
    drawLine(ctx, a, c, "red");
    text(ctx, a, "A", "black");
    text(ctx, b, "B", "black");
    text(ctx, c, "C", "red");
}

let ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
let inputDegrees = document.querySelector("#angle");
let outputB = document.querySelector("#b");
let a = { x: 200, y: 75 };

ctx.canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    let b = { 
        x: e.clientX-e.target.offsetLeft,
        y: e.clientY-e.target.offsetTop,
    };
    let c = getC(a, b, inputDegrees.value*Math.PI/180);
    refresh(ctx, a, b, c);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
Angle(degrees): <input id="angle" type="number" value="15"><br>
A=(200,75) B=(<span id="b"></span>)<br>

<canvas width="400" height="150"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, say when you have a circle with center A(x,y) and radius r. The position of the initial point is θ radians along the circle from (a+r,b).

The parametric equation for the circle is (x,y)=(a + r cosθ,b + r sinθ).

In your case, you want to increase by ϕ radians. Then the new point is
(a+ r  cos(θ+ϕ),b+ r  sin(θ+ϕ))

Perhaps, if you could provide more explanation to your question. it will aid more into solution.  Meanwhile i will dig for answer without radius i.e distance between A & B